# How can I add darker transperency into my relativelayout, like in the image?

Tags: java, android

I tried to do many things: set alpha value, set background:transparency, set backgroud different colors like "#90000000", I even created another view with transparency above my reciclerView. But I always have one result:

[image]

(do not look at white pictures, I will set them later)

And I need transparency like that one:

[image]

So as you see image and line are not under transparency. Do you have any ideas how fix it?

Comment: whats ur code look like.

Answer (score 1):

I think you declare the RecyclerView in the front of root,
if you are using a RelativeLayout like a main View in the xml layout, you have to make sur that your transparent View below your RecyclerView, this is an example:

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
</RecyclerView>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9A000000"> 
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: He already tried this he says "I even created another view with transparency above my reciclerView". You just assume he did it wrong?

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes bro, I am sur he reverse the arrangement

Answer (score 0):

you can define two image view and first set the background your image and for secondly set the other background.but you must set the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a overlay above this recyclerview. Just like this.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:translationZ="100dp"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

LinearLayout works as overlay